# DataContractJsonSerializer returning null object

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time now, and can't solve it.
I have the following JSON string:

```
 {"Search":[{"Title":"somestring","Year":"somestring","imdbID":"somestring"}]}, {"Title":"somestring","Year":"somestring","imdbID":"somestring"} etc
```

The string can repeat itself multiple times, so I want to store the values in a list. In order to do this I've created the following two classes:
The SuggestionListener class:

```
[DataContract]
class SuggestionLister
{
    public List<MovieResults> suggestionlist {get;set;}
}
```

Which holds the List I want returned.

And the Movieresults class:

```
[DataContract]
class MovieResults
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Year { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string imdbID { get; set; }

}
```

Which hold the data that needs to be stored. I tried Deserializing it with the following code:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resp);
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(data);
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new    DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SuggestionLister));
SuggestionLister suggestionMovies = (SuggestionLister)serializer.ReadObject(memStream);
```

Where the 'resp' variable is the JSON string. However, when I try this code the suggestMovies object remains null. What is wrong?

Comment: Make sure , your json is this only?? It has different patterns in between....

Comment: Yes, sorry the format isn't quite correct here is an exact copy: '{"Search":[{"Title":"Inception","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1375666"},{"Title":"Inception: Motion Comics","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1790736"},{"Title":"Inception: 4Movie Premiere Special","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1686778"},{"Title":"WWA: The Inception","Year":"2001","imdbID":"tt0311992"},{"Title":"Inception","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1695201"}]}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so there are a couple of issues:

```
[DataContract]
public class SuggestionLister
{
     [DataMember]
    public List<MovieResults> Search { get; set; }
}
```

You do not have DataMember attribute on your list property and it needs to  match the name of the array value which is "Search".

Edit:  I tested all of this using your code.  Also the format of your JSON that you posted is not correct, but I am assuming that is a pasting error.

Comment: Thank you! This in combination with the previous comment about the name of the property worked! Feel kind of stupid not thinking about it, sorry to have bothered you with it!

Comment: No problem, easy to overlook and the DataContractJsonSerializer has lots of issues.

Comment: If you do not want to rename the actual property, you can set the name in the DataMember attribute. `[DataMember(Name = "Search")]`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[DataContract]
class SuggestionLister
{
   public List<MovieResults> Search {get;set;}
}
```

Since your json seems to be of this format:

```
{
  "Search": [ { "Title": ... }]
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, same result. The Search property remains to be null.

Comment: Is the Json string in your question the actual string you are using? It looks like it's malformed.

Comment: No, as I've stated in the comment above me it is not. Sorry for the confusion, it's the output from this link: http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Inception