# Serialize JSON array from a web request

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I am making what should be a very simple JSON request from a script task from SSIS. The URL return is very large, 20 million characters.

The first URL return line looks like this:

```
[{"brandId":"9","season":"SG","year":"2003","bomNumber":"00011111","costId":"00001","bomCCNumber":"0000008","firstCost":1.01,"landedFactor":1.234,"elc":9.876,"market":"MA","channel":"CH","destinationCountry":"DC"},...
```

I've run the URL return through a parser and verified that it is well-formed.

Here is my code.

```
[DataContract]
public class CostingNegotiated
{

    [DataMember(Name = "brandId")]
    public string brandId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "season")]
    public string season { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "year")]
    public string year { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "bomNumber")]
    public string bomNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "costId")]
    public string CostID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "bomCCNumber")]
    public string bomCCNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "firstCost")]
    public string firstCost { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "landedFactor")]
    public double landedFactor { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "elc")]
    public double elc { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "market")]
    public string market { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "channel")]
    public string channel { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "destinationCountry")]
    public string destinationCountry { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CostingNegotiatedList")]
    public List<CostingNegotiated> CostingNegotiatedList { get; set; }
}

private RootObject GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl)
{

    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);
    httpWReq.Method = "GET";
    httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWReq.Timeout = 300000;
    HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
    RootObject jsonResponse = null;

    try
    {
        //Get the stream of JSON
        Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();

        //Deserialize the JSON stream
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            string r = reader.ReadToEnd();

            //Deserialize our JSON
            DataContractJsonSerializer sr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(r));
            jsonResponse = (RootObject)sr.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
    //Output JSON parsing error
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FailComponent(e.ToString());
    }
    return jsonResponse;

}
```

I've verified that the string variable r has the JSON string. When I get to this line:

```
jsonResponse = (RootObject)sr.ReadObject(ms);
```

The jsonResponse has a RootObject, but the CostingNegotiatedList list variable is NULL. What do I need to do to get this list to populate?

Comment: When you say you've checked the URL return, you've ensured you aren't running into length problems as outlined in these articles? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: So my actual URL request is pretty short. The RETURN VALUE is extremely long, and I am not 100% sure it's not causing problems. I'm not very familiar with JSON or C#. However, I'm not getting any exceptions on the code. It's just not loading my list object.

Comment: Being a list, do you need to instantiate a new instance of it before values can be set to it? Another possible scenario is it might need assistance getting from an array to a list.

Comment: I ... don't think so? I took a sample off another page, and I referred to this SO question to check my syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884062/datacontractjsonserializer-returning-null-object?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My JSON doesn't have a header element, it's just a straight list, so I don't need my RootObject variable. I changed my code to refer to a list of my objects:

private List GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl)
{

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);
httpWReq.Method = "GET";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWReq.Timeout = 300000;
HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
List<CostingNegotiated> jsonResponse = null;

try
{
    //Get the stream of JSON
    Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();

    //Deserialize the JSON stream
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        string r = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //Deserialize our JSON
        DataContractJsonSerializer sr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<CostingNegotiated>));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(r));
        jsonResponse = (List<CostingNegotiated>)sr.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
//Output JSON parsing error
catch (Exception e)
{
    FailComponent(e.ToString());
}
return jsonResponse;
```

Comment: One improvement you could make-- you seem to be reading the response stream using a `StreamReader`, then putting it back into a `MemoryStream` only to read it again with the serializer.  You shouldn't need to do that-- just give the responseStream directly to the serializer: `sr.ReadObject(responseStream);`